# GLSL layering textures with alpha and no multiplication

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I'm hoping there might be a GLSL guru out there who can help with this one, 
I'm attempting to blend three textures together using three separate textures as the alpha channels (black and white images), I would like them to stack on top of each other without multiplying the brightness of the one underneath, but im using threejs and the ShaderMaterial class. I can successfully map the opactiy on each layer but when I'm attempting to combine them they seem to multiply and blend weirdly (meaning the image gets brighter with each layer applied on top)

Examples of the textures I am using below...

Diffusive:

[image: Diffusive]

Alpha maps (black and white):

[image: Alphas]

my fragment shader is as such.....

```
            #ifdef GL_ES
            precision highp float;
            #endif

            uniform sampler2D tOne;
            uniform sampler2D tSec;
            uniform sampler2D tThi;

            uniform sampler2D aOne;
            uniform sampler2D aSec;
            uniform sampler2D aThi;

            varying vec2 vUv;


            void main(void)
            {
                vec3 c;
                vec3 d;
                vec3 e;
                vec3 f;

                vec3 m1;
                vec3 m2;

                vec4 Ca = texture2D(tOne, vUv);
                vec4 Cb = texture2D(tSec, vUv);
                vec4 Cc = texture2D(tThi, vUv);
                vec4 Aa = texture2D(aOne, vUv);
                vec4 Ab = texture2D(aSec, vUv);
                vec4 Ac = texture2D(aThi, vUv);

                c = (Ca.rgb * Aa.rgb)*1.0;
                d = (Cb.rgb * Ab.rgb)*1.0;
                e = (Cc.rgb * Ac.rgb)*1.0;

                f = (c.rgb + d.rgb + e.rgb * (1.0))*1.0;

                gl_FragColor= vec4(f, 1.0);

            }
```

and if i run it with ......

```
gl_FragColor= vec4(c, 1.0);
```

result:

[image: c]

or

```
gl_FragColor= vec4(d, 1.0);
```

result:

[image: d]

or

```
gl_FragColor= vec4(e, 1.0);
```

result:

[image: e]

I can see each layer with the correct opacity and rgb values
but as i say im having trouble combining them so that they stay at the correct rgb values, they seem to multiply and get brighter at the moment.

I had read somewhere about specifying a blendmode as its turned on by default. But im not sure how you would turn this off on something like threejs.

Current Result:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

Or perhaps my calculation just needs fixing for the combining of the layers

Any help with this would be much appreciated?

Thankyou all for your time!

-Rhys Thomas

---

### Worked!!

**MarGenDo** - you are a **star**!!! , you were right i had to start adding inverted parts of alpha in order for it to get through to the next layer.

Heres it all working and the modified alphas as you suggested!!

[image: Working]

Correct alphas:

[image: correct alphas]

Although im sure i can try and do some of this merging of alphas with the shader your logic is absolutely sound!

Thanks again **MarGenDo**

---

So Works again

Firstly thankyou to both MarGenDo and the legendary gman, the solution that worked best for me was gmans, as I can not deal with minus'ing alphas etc, the mix command worked beautifully!!! Also if you want to see it in action please take a look at http://www.polygonprophecy.com/html5/Island - best viewed on a phone as it allows you to zoom in and out (pinch and punch) and also rotate around the island (two finger rotate), its now very speedy down to the use of good shader programming (thankyou both again!!!), hopefully works speedy on a bad phones also! **gman your a bloody star!!**

As a note, this was my end result shader:-

```
        #ifdef GL_ES
        precision highp float;
        #endif

        uniform sampler2D tOne;
        uniform sampler2D tSec;
        uniform sampler2D tThi;

        uniform sampler2D aOne;
        uniform sampler2D aSec;
        uniform sampler2D aThi;

        varying vec2 vUv;


        void main(void)
        {
            vec4 Ca = texture2D(tOne, vUv);
            vec4 Cb = texture2D(tSec, vUv);
            vec4 Cc = texture2D(tThi, vUv);
            vec4 Aa = texture2D(aOne, vUv);
            vec4 Ab = texture2D(aSec, vUv);
            vec4 Ac = texture2D(aThi, vUv);
            vec4 g;

            g = vec4(0);

            g = mix(g, Ca, Aa);
            g = mix(g, Cb, Ab);
            g = mix(g, Cc, Ac);

            gl_FragColor= vec4(g.rgb, Aa.rgb+Ab.rgb+Ac.rgb);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this might work with your original alpha textures

```
            vec4 Ca = texture2D(tOne, vUv);
            vec4 Cb = texture2D(tSec, vUv);
            vec4 Cc = texture2D(tThi, vUv);
            vec4 Aa = texture2D(aOne, vUv);
            vec4 Ab = texture2D(aSec, vUv);
            vec4 Ac = texture2D(aThi, vUv);

            // This is the default color. 
            // The color when all the alphas are zero
            f = vec4(0);

            f = mix(f, Ca, Aa);
            f = mix(f, Cb, Ab);
            f = mix(f, Cc, Ac);

            gl_FragColor= vec4(f, 1.0);
```

Trying it out

```js
"use strict";
var gl = twgl.getWebGLContext(document.getElementById("c"));
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

var arrays = {
  position: [-1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
};
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

var textures = twgl.createTextures(gl, {
  tOne: { src: "https://i.imgur.com/P5bZckC.jpg", crossOrigin: "", },
  tSec: { src: "https://i.imgur.com/2FI5CHY.jpg", crossOrigin: "", },
  tThi: { src: "https://i.imgur.com/YV0Wrxn.jpg", crossOrigin: "", },
  aOne: { src: "https://i.imgur.com/Kzk0cEx.jpg", crossOrigin: "", },
  aSec: { src: "https://i.imgur.com/weFi9dr.jpg", crossOrigin: "", },
  aThi: { src: "https://i.imgur.com/Ebkh1j1.jpg", crossOrigin: "", },
}, function() {
  
  var uniforms = {
    tOne: textures.tOne,
    tSec: textures.tSec,
    tThi: textures.tThi,
    aOne: textures.aOne,
    aSec: textures.aSec,
    aThi: textures.aThi,
  };

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);

});
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
attribute vec4 position;

varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  vUv = position.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;


uniform sampler2D tOne;
uniform sampler2D tSec;
uniform sampler2D tThi;

uniform sampler2D aOne;
uniform sampler2D aSec;
uniform sampler2D aThi;

varying vec2 vUv;


void main(void)
{
  vec4 f;

  vec4 Ca = texture2D(tOne, vUv);
  vec4 Cb = texture2D(tSec, vUv);
  vec4 Cc = texture2D(tThi, vUv);
  vec4 Aa = texture2D(aOne, vUv);
  vec4 Ab = texture2D(aSec, vUv);
  vec4 Ac = texture2D(aThi, vUv);

  // This is the default color. 
  // The color when all the alphas are zero
  f = vec4(0);

  f = mix(f, Ca, Aa);
  f = mix(f, Cb, Ab);
  f = mix(f, Cc, Ac);

  gl_FragColor= vec4(f.rgb, 1.0);
}
  </script>
  <script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="128" height="128"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi gman, I did attempt this unfortunately it seems that threejs shader throws an error or sorts with the mix operator. However I have started to merge the alphas using the shader another way, still having a little difficulty but will try and post something tonight depending on how far I get. It seems to be running into a similar problem even though the code seems logical to me. So again I will try and post something hopefully yourself or margendo can help me with. Thanks -Rhys Thomas @MarGenDo

Comment: Ah my bad gman it does work, perfect in fact i just had to change this line.... gl_FragColor= vec4(f, 1.0); to gl_FragColor= vec4(f.rgb, 1.0);

Comment: Thanks again will try properly again at home and post results

Answer (score 2):

Well, your problem is in your alpha textures. You have to change them a bit. For example in the middle you are adding up color values of all three textures but you only want to see one of them (rock texture). Every alpha texture except the rock should be black in the middle.

This is an example how your sand alpha texture should look like.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNzNP.jpg]

(sorry for my ugly drawing but I hope you understand what I mean)

Comment: Ahh I see, of course I should be combining those alpha textures each layer up I go, nice catch!!! I will give this a go tonight and get back to you!!

Comment: Thanks! If you have any other questions feel free to ask :)